# How can I orderby in schema.yml doctrine symfony 1.4

Tags: orm, symfony1, doctrine, schema, many-to-many

I've got a many to many relationship from Project to Asset using ProjectAsset class as middle class between this 2. When I use getProjectAsset() method on a project it returns all my ProjectAssets assigned to that project.

How can I change the schema.yml to order the results by default?

```
Project:
  relations:
    Assets:
      class: Asset
      refClass: ProjectAsset
      foreignAlias: Projects
      local: project_id
      foreign: asset_id           

ProjectAsset:
  tableName: projects_assets
  columns:
    title: { type: string, length: 255 }
    project_id:  { type: integer, primary: true }
    asset_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Project:
      class: Project
      foreignAlias: ProjectAssetRelations
      local: project_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Asset:
      class: Asset
      foreignAlias: ProjectAssetRelations
      local: asset_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is my first thought after reading http://www.dobervich.com/2011/03/05/symfony2-blog-application-tutorial-part-ii-the-data-model/ Haven't tested yet, though.

```
oneToMany:
    posts:
        targetEntity: Post
        orderBy:
            createdAt: DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's an easy way to achieve sorting without the use of querybuilders/criteria and such! And it even works for nested entity columns! Cheers!

Comment: This does not work at all for me. I'm using Symfony 2.5

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be done in schema.yml file but when retrieving the data in the code.

Eg.

```
$passets = Doctrine_Query::create()
           ->select('p.*')
           ->from('ProjectAsset  p')
           ->orderBy("p.Title")
           ->execute();
```

Update: Maybe you can: [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632922/iterate-doctrine-collection-ordered-by-some-field/3312277#3312277).